# Parsing A Simple Matrix Definition In C

Tags: c, parsing

In one of my homework projects, I have to parse a matrix definition into a matrix data structure in C. The elements of the matrix will be given in a list of double. I need a simple tokenizer and parser for the task naturally, but I have not much experience in parsing. I implemented the tokenizer and parser. The tokenizer produces a few types of tokens. The list of token types includes `tokEot` (ie. End of tokens), `tokId`, `tokNumber`, `tokOparen`, `tokCparen`, `tokComma`, `tokAssign`. The matrix definition will be in the form of `identifier(Integer, Integer) = ( Real Number, Real Number, ... , Real Number)`. The input can have more than one matrix definition. The name of the data structure for the tokenizer is `scanner`. I have no data structure for the parser, implemented it in a single function(`parse_matrix`). I need also error checking in the parsing stage, so if the order in the definition of a matrix is not be followed, then I must report an error and exit the program. You can look at the supplementary code for more details. The program works without any problems. However, since I need a code review specifically for the function `parse_matrix` and it might be redundant, I don't want to include the source code of the tokenizer (maybe in another question). Here is the code with the all necessary parts.

````
typedef struct matrix { 
    char* name; // The name of the matrix, the parsed identifiers will be stored here.
    int m; // The number of rows
    int n; // The number of cols
    double* elements; // A chunk of doubles  
}matrix;

// The enum for the token types
typedef enum token_type
{
    tokEot, // End of tokens
    tokId,  // Identifier
    tokNumber, // Either int or double
    tokOparen, // (
    tokCparen, // )
    tokComma,  // ,
    tokAssign, // =
    tokCount
}token_type;

typedef struct token_t
{
    token_type type;
    union
    {
        double data_double;
        char* data_string;
        int data_int;
    };
}token_t;

typedef struct scanner
{
    token_t current_token; // Last generated token
    char* input_string; // Input string that contains matrix definitions
    char* current_char; // Current character to be processed.
}scanner;

token_t next_token(scanner* pthis);
matrix* parse_matrix(scanner* pscanner);
void handle_error(const char* error_text);
matrix* new_matrix(char* name, int m, int n);

int main()
{
    char* input = "mat1(3, 3) = ( 1.0, -3.0, 5.0, "
        "2.0, -1.0, 5.0, "
        "1.0, -3.0, 5.0 )";
     
    scanner* float_scanner = new_scanner(input);
    matrix* mat1 = parse_matrix(float_scanner); 
    system("pause");
}

matrix* new_matrix(char* name, int m, int n)
{
    matrix* mat = malloc(sizeof(matrix));
    mat->m = m;
    mat->n = n;
    mat->name = name;
    mat->elements = malloc(sizeof(double) * m * n);
    return mat;
}

// tokId --> ( --> Int --> , --> Int --> ) --> = --> ( --> Double --> , --> Double ... --> ) 
matrix* parse_matrix(scanner* pthis)
{
    matrix* mat;
    int count = 0;
    char* id_name = NULL;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    token_t pre_token;
    token_t token;
    do
    {
        token = next_token(pthis);
        //If token type is a identifier, then we will try to parse a matrix declaration.
        if (token.type == tokId)
        {
            // Duplicate the token data
            id_name = strdup(token.data_string);
            token = next_token(pthis); 
            // I must have an open parenthesis after an identifier 
            if (token.type == tokOparen)
            {
                token = next_token(pthis);
                // Parsing the dimensions of the matrix
                if (token.type == tokNumber)
                {
                    m = token.data_int;
                    token = next_token(pthis);
                    // There is a comma between the dimensions of matrix 
                    if (token.type == tokComma)
                    {
                        token = next_token(pthis);
                        // A number must follow the comma
                        if (token.type == tokNumber)
                        {
                            n = token.data_int;
                            token = next_token(pthis);
                            if (token.type == tokCparen)
                            {
                                // Allocate the matrix with the specified dimensions.
                                mat = new_matrix(id_name, m, n);
                                token = next_token(pthis);
                                if (token.type == tokAssign)
                                {
                                    token = next_token(pthis);
                                    if (token.type == tokOparen)
                                    {
                                        token = next_token(pthis);
                                        // Finally, parse the elements.
                                        if (token.type == tokNumber)
                                            *(mat->elements + count++) = token.data_double;
                                        else
                                            handle_error("Expected a number after open paranthesis.");
                                        do
                                        {
                                            token = next_token(pthis);
                                            if (token.type == tokCparen)
                                                break;
                                            if (token.type == tokComma)
                                            {
                                                token = next_token(pthis);
                                                if (token.type == tokNumber)
                                                    *(mat->elements + count++) = token.data_double;
                                                else
                                                    handle_error("Expected a number after a comma.");
                                            }
                                            else
                                                handle_error("Expected a comma after a number.");

                                        } while (token.type != tokCparen);
                                        // If the user didn't specify enough elements, we should
                                        // fill the rest with zero.
                                        if (count < m * n)
                                            for (int i = count; i < m * n; i++)
                                                *(mat->elements + i) = 0.0;

                                        return mat;
                                    }
                                    else
                                        handle_error("Expected an open parenthesis after an assignment.");
                                }
                                else
                                    handle_error("Expected an assigment.");
                            }
                            else
                                handle_error("Expected a close parenthesis.");
                        }
                        else
                            handle_error("Expected a integer number.");
                    }
                    else
                        handle_error("Expected a comma.");
                }
                else
                    handle_error("Expected a integer number.");
            }
            else
                handle_error("Expected an open parenthesis.");
        }


    } while (token.type != tokEot);
}
void handle_error(const char* error_text)
{
    perror(error_text);
    exit(-1);
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code looks pretty good. I prefer some other [style guide](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), but this looks consistent, and consistency is important too.

#### Indentation

Arbitrarily, you can spell the string constant like this:

```
char* input = 
  "mat1(3, 3) = "
  "( 1.0, -3.0, 5.0, "
    "2.0, -1.0, 5.0, "
    "1.0, -3.0, 5.0 )";
```

Placing the similar tokens directly one under another can find errors in those tokens in a moment.

#### Unit tests

You should test your code. There are literally dozens of [unit test frameworks for C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C); and using unit tests will make you immediately find if new changes would break something later. Just do it. Besides, you're *already* testing the code, but in a much less efficient way - this code has one test in a `main()` function.

#### Mixing model and presentation

Data transformations should be some inner job, usually called model, while reporting errors to user is for presentation. The parser would be much more portable and reusable if it wouldn't rely on a specific output system, maybe returning NULL on errors.

#### `system("pause");`

The worst thing in this code. It relies on specific OS and calls a far more complex program than this one for just one discarded input. Your IDE probably has some tools to capture the output after the program exit, just [look for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

#### `if-else` staircase

I think this is why you've posted the code here. Well, it may be a good habit to put more likely option into the `if` branch and less likely into the `else`; but here the execution stops on `handle_error`, so it can be rewritten in a much more linear way:

```
token = next_token(pthis); 
if (token.type != tokOparen)
   handle_error("Expected an open parenthesis.");

token = next_token(pthis);
if (token.type != tokNumber)
   handle_error("Expected a integer number.");
```

etc. This will make the code not so structured (though it isn't structured now), but much more readable - except for one detail. It's not clear for readers that `handle_error` breaks the execution. So, maybe, it should be something like

```
token = next_token(pthis); 
if (token.type != tokOparen)
   return handle_error("Expected an open parenthesis.");

token = next_token(pthis);
if (token.type != tokNumber)
   return handle_error("Expected a integer number.");
```

This looks much better. Of course, `handle_error` now should `return NULL` after `exit(-1)`. Maybe commented out to avoid compiler warnings.

One other option for such situations is a `do-while(false);` construction:

```
do { //while(false) - you should always comment this
    do_some_work();
    if(something_wrong())
        break;

    do_some_more_work();
    if(one thing more wrong)
        break;

    do_even_more_work();
    if(still wrong)
        break;

    do_final_work();
} while(false);
```

Comment: +1 for your answer. But I cannot upvote since I have not enough reputation. That linear way sounds better!

Comment: I needed really such a style guide, +1 also for that link.